# how to delete izpack installer window services via control panel

Tags: java, izpack, procrun

I am working with java window service i am using Apache Procrun  for creating service and izpack for java installer and launch4j for convert  jar into exe.
I know in izpack have an option to add installer to control panel by adding COIOSHelper.dll" file in native tag  and its work perfectly  but izpack uninstaller jar deletes only the installation directory only. Services is not deleted so how to delete the service along with installed directory via control panel. izpack have any option to do that ? give me some idea ???

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom action listener for this, e.g. the [AntActionUninstallerListener](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/AntActionInstallerListener+and+AntActionUninstallerListener)

Please note that you need administrator rights to manipulate services, so you will to run with `<run-privileged>`.